# Python - put_item() S3, Lambda, DynamoDB -- An error occurred (ValidationException)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am using python with the AWS S3, lambda and DynamoDB. I have my lambda function set up as a trigger. When I drop a .json file into my S3 bucket, it will activate.

When my function activates, it errors once it reaches my put_item function call that is supposed to be storing the json object in my dynamodb table.

#### The error text:

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException)
when calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values
were invalid: Missing the key test in the item
```

I have tried to change the arguments within the `table.put_item(TableName='testTable', Item = jsonDict)`, but the documents I was following before only passed one argument to this function.

Any advice or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

#### My Code states:

```
import boto3
import json

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    json_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=json_file_name)
    jsonFileReader = json_object['Body'].read()
    jsonDict = json.loads(jsonFileReader)
    table = dynamodb.Table('test')
    table.put_item(Item = jsonDict)

    return 'Hello from lambda'
```

#### CLOUD WATCH LOGS:

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when
calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values were
invalid: Missing the key test in the item
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 14, in lambda_handler
    response = table.put_item(Item = jsonDict)
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 320, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 623, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

#### EDITS:

I created my table with the 'test' primary key and the 'test' table name, leaving all of the other settings to default within the AWS dynamo table creation GUI.

#### json file contents:

{ "test": { "name": "Cody", "age": 27, "car": true } }

Comment: The error is saying that the JSON you are putting into DynamoDB does not have a key of `test`. Please edit your question to show the design of the DynamoDB table (does it have a hash key of `test`?) and a sample of the data you are loading into `jsonDict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `{"name": "Cody", "age": 27, "car": true}` as the value of the primary key. In DynamoDB, a primary (partition) key can only be of [type string, binary or number](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey).

As an example, using `{"test": "Cody", "age": 27, "car": True}` as the `Item` argument to `put_item` would work.

Or if you would change the partition key name in the table to `name`, calling `table.put_item(Item=jsonDict['test'])` would also do the trick.

Comment: I reformatted my JSON to include a primary key of test just like you said. This worked perfectly. Thank you Milan.

Comment: Yay, I'm glad it helped. Feel free to upvote and accept the answer so that others can recognize it as helpful too.

Comment: I need two more reputation and I will then be able to begin upvoting. Once I get it, I will upvote your answer immediately. I promise.